# Determine the matrix A that represents T in the canonical form of R2[x] in the start and in the end

Tags: linear-algebra

Being T: R2[x]->R2[x] defined in T(ax^2+bx+c)=2ax+b

Determine the matrix A that represents T in the canonical form of R2[x] in the start and in the end

My conclusions until now:

T(1)=0
T(x)=1
T(x^2)=2x

I don't know how to use this to make the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write the matrix of this homomorphism (the method holds for every linear map) $$T: \mathbb{R}_2[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_2[x]$$ we first choose a base for for the domain and one for the image: the exercise here requires the canonical basis for either two, which is $\mathcal{B} = \{1, x, x^2\}$. Then to determine the matrix $[T]$ associated to the map you just have to evaluate the application on the basis, in this case: $$T(1) = 0\;\;\;\;T(x) = 1\;\;\;\; T(x^2) = 2x$$ and write the result as a linear combination of the basis of the image (in this case it remains the same), so: $$\mathbf{v}_1=T(1) = 0*1 + 0*x+0*x^2 \\ \mathbf{v}_2=T(x) = 1*1 + 0*x +0*x^2 \\ \mathbf{v}_3=T(x^2) = 0*1 + 2*x +0*x^2$$
The coordinate of the three vectors in the base of the image are then $$\mathbf{v}_1 = (0,0,0)\;\;\;\;\mathbf{v}_2=(1,0,0)\;\;\;\;\mathbf{v}_3=(0,2,0)$$ Finally the matrix of the map is to be written as

$$\left( \begin{matrix}|&|&|\\
\mathbf{v}_1&\mathbf{v}_2&\mathbf{v}_3\\
|&|&|\end{matrix}\right) = \left( \begin{matrix}0&1&0\\
0&0&2\\
0&0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

You can check if this is right by taking a generic vector $\mathbf{v}=(c,b,a) = c+bx+ax^2$ and seeing if the product of this with the matrix gets you were you wanted to be 
$$\left( \begin{matrix}0&1&0\\
0&0&2\\
0&0&0\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}c\\b\\a\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}b\\2a\\0\end{matrix}\right) = b+2ax$$
as the exercise stated.

### Justification

If it wasn't clear, you take the product with the matrix because, if you have the matrix associated with your map (which is unique after choosing the basis) you can write the map as: $$T(\mathbf{v}) = [T]\mathbf{v}^T$$

### Just for fun

I really loved the notation used by Lang to write the matrix of a linear map $$L:V_{\mathcal{B}}\rightarrow W_{\mathcal{C}}$$ where the subscript denotes the basis chosen for each vecor space. He denotes the matrix as $$[L]^{\mathcal{B}}_{\mathcal{C}}$$ which I found very useful when dealing with map composition

Comment: and write the result as a linear combination of the basis of the image (in this case it remains the same)

I couldn't follow the calculus

For T(1)=0, following (1,x,x^2) we have 0*1+0*x+0*x^2 i could understand

T(x)=1 i got stuck and couldn't understand the 1*1 (i must be dumb)

Comment: That's no shame, it happens to everybody!

Comment: @PedroQuintans By the way, I think for future reference you should accept the answer so that it will show on MSE as a closed question!

Comment: Sorry about that, i'm new to this site, i already closed it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the ‘canonical form’ denotes the *canonical basis* $\{1, x, x^2  \}$ of $\:\mathbf R_2[X]$.

**Hint**:

The column vectors of this  $3\times 3$ matrix are the coordinates in the canonical basis of the images of the vectors of this canonical basis.

Comment: Sorry, can you provide an example?

Comment: In your case, for instance $T(x^2)=2x$. So the coordinates of $T(x^2)$ in basis $(1,x,x^2)$   are $(0, 2,0)$ (transposed).

Comment: how? i don't understand, you replace the x from the (1,X,x^2) for 2x?

Comment: Because $2x=\color{red}0\cdot 1+\color{red}2\cdot x+\color{red}0\cdot x^2$, that's all!